# Custom Xamarin Cell Issue

Tags: mobile, xamarin, cross-platform

I'm learning to use Xamarin, and was making a simple custom cell.  However, when I run the app none of the information I set as the ListViews ItemsSource displays.  I was wondering if there was an issue with the way I was binding the information or if it was an issue with the way I was constructing the custom cell.

Here is the cell class:

```
public class ButtonCell : ViewCell
{
    #region Constructors
    public ButtonCell()
    {
        //Button bg = new Button();
        Label title = new Label()
        {
            TextColor = Color.Black,
            FontSize = 12,
            YAlign = TextAlignment.Start
        };

        Label description = new Label()
        {
            TextColor = Color.Black,
            FontSize = 12,
            YAlign = TextAlignment.End
        };

        title.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Title"));
        description.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Budget"));

        Grid labelLayout = new Grid()
        {
            /*VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,*/
            Padding = new Thickness(5, 0, 5, 10),
            Children = 
            {
                title, 
                description
            }
        };

        View = labelLayout;

        /*Grid grid = new Grid()
        {
            Padding = new Thickness(5, 0, 5, 10),
            Children = 
            {
                bg,
                labelLayout
            }
        };*/
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Here is the class that I want to display information from in the list view:

```
public class Bucket
{
    #region Public Variables
    public string Title;
    public float Budget;
    public BucketType Type;
    public BucketCategory Category;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public Bucket()
    {
        Title = "";
        Budget = 0;
        Type = (BucketType)0;
        Category = (BucketCategory)0;
    }

    public Bucket(string title, float budget, BucketType type, BucketCategory category)
    {
        Title = title;
        Budget = budget;
        Type = type;
        Category = category;
    }
    #endregion
}

public enum BucketType
{
    Flexible = 0,
    Fixed
}

public enum BucketCategory
{
    Bills = 0,
    Food,
    Hobbies
}
```

When I initialize the list view, it displays the appropriate number of cell.  However, none of the information is display.  Once again, I'm not sure if its a binding issue or maybe a formatting issue with the cell.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: your bindable values (Title, Budget, etc) need to be public properties, not just public member variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following member variables in the Bucket class need changing to properties:

```
#region Public Variables
public string Title;
public float Budget;
public BucketType Type;
public BucketCategory Category;
#endregion
```

Needs changing to:

```
#region Public Variables
public string Title {get;set;};
public float Budget{get;set;};
public BucketType Type{get;set;};
public BucketCategory Category{get;set;};
#endregion
```

You also need to implement IPrpopertyChanged in order to make the bindings anything other than OneWay. I use a nugget package called Fody.PropertyChanged but the implementation is up to you.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the help!